# More succinct way to get total number of unique items

Tags: javascript, foreach

This is my code to get the total number of unique fruit colours by adding each fruit to a set. It is written in 3 lines, I am curious as to whether I can make it into a one-liner code?

```
  const fruitSet = new Set();
  allFruits.forEach(fruit => fruitSet.add(fruit.color));
  const totalUniqueColors = fruitSet.size;
```

Update:
I should add that all fruits take this structure and there are >50 fruits:

```
{
   fruit: strawberry
   color: red,
   price: 2.50
},
{
   fruit: watermelon
   color: red,
   price: 5
},
{
   fruit: avocado
   color: green,
   price: 7
},
{
   fruit: banana
   color: yellow,
   price: 1
},
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just need the count. you can instantiate a set by passing an iterator into it.

```
new Set(allFruits.map(({color}) => color)).size
```

Comment: the count of all unique fruits and count of all unique colors may not be the same, so i can't pass in allFruits

Comment: @codingismypassion in which case `new Set(allFruits.map(f=>f.color)).size` would be my preference.